# JSON parse in SQL with hash key

Tags: json, sql-server, blockchain, sql-server-2019

I have a table with a JSON column. in this column I have a blockchain hash data.
for example this JSON:

```
{  "017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894": {
"transaction": {
  "block_id": 648895,
  "id": 568135560,
  "hash": "017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894",
  "date": "2020-01-14",
  "time": "2020-01-14 11:37:37",
  "size": 198,
},
"inputs": [
  {
    "block_id": 648859,
    "transaction_id": 567456558,
    "index": 4,
    "transaction_hash": "8aa2c6c9a804mate29790e03fac462782d99f16614732f82a5214786926e1397",
    "date": "2020-01-13",
    "time": "2020-01-13 23:15:37",
    "value": 300830,
    "value_usd": 33.2264,
    "recipient": "1LcrmomE74BPzBTdduE8WHU2ox4QAFEpQi",

  }
],
"outputs": [
  {
    "block_id": 648445,
    "transaction_id": 568146680,
    "index": 0,
    "transaction_hash": "017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894",
    "date": "2020-01-14",
    "time": "2020-01-14 11:37:37",
    "value": 300048,
    "value_usd": 31.9397,
    "recipient": "12UJZqf4sDGRNb9uYBABJkMyX91iLjDViT",

  }
]}}
```

I used below query:

```
SELECT *, JSON_VALUE(d.json_data,'$.017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894.transaction.size') as jj
FROM BlockChain as d
```

but I have an error

> Msg 13607, Level 16, State 4, Line 39
> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '0' is found at position 2.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path
`'$.017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894.transaction.size'`
cannot have a node starting with a 0. [So enclose it in quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#PATH):
`'$."017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894".transaction.size'`.

You also have a problem with your actual JSON, in that it has trailing commas, which is not supported in SQL Server, nor in the vast majority of parsers and browsers, as it is against the spec.

---

If you have different key names for each value, then you need to break out the JSON with `OPENJSON`:

```sql
SELECT b.*, j.[key] AS hash, JSON_VALUE(j.value,'$.transaction.size') as jj
FROM BlockChain as d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.json_data) AS j
```

Comment: with this '$."017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894".transaction.size'  unfortunately return null !!

Comment: Are you sure that's an exact match on that key?

Comment: excuse me. your answer is correct. I call '$."017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894".transaction that return null. but '$."017989w06d3f902f1f362dfg48f862dba6a605229e99859a91d854f93ac13894".transaction.size return correct answer.

Comment: Have made further update for changing hash keys